# In JavaFX CSS class selector doesn't work when some nodes of the class has been selected elsewhere using id selector?

Tags: css, javafx

```
.button:pressed{
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

#spin{
    -fx-background-color : blue;
}
```

This is a simple example to demonstrate it. In the first line I use a class selector to change all buttons when pressed. In the second line I use a id to change the appearance of a specific button only.

The spin button is blue initially. When I press it it's supposed to turn black. But it doesn't turn black when I press it.

But when I comment out the second line #spin. Now, the pressing effect works. How do I fix this?

I want to style some buttons individually but want to give the same effect for all of them when pressed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the ":pressed" event for the id selectors as well, where you will do

```
.button:pressed, #spin:pressed{
    -fx-background-color:black;
}
```

In your case, you have overridden the pressed event since you used a different css for the id selected button, however using this method you will be able to overcome this issue.